# Integrate Google\Firebase account setup in my app setup

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since my apps will rely on Firebase Realtime Database\Cloud Messaging, is there a way to integrate the initial creation of the Google account and Firebase project during my app install?

Comment: Generally your project needs to be created in the Firebase console and data from that project included in your code (the plist file in iOS for example). So no, you can't really create a project on they fly per se but then again, why would you? You have to write code, test it etc and to do that the previously mentioned data would need to be included to do that. Can you clarify your question with a use case?

Comment: For instance, you have a desktop application used by businesses to share business-related data with customers (via their mobile devices).  You also have a mobile app for use by customers.  When a business installs your desktop application, a Google account\Firebase project are  created for that business.  Once created, customers could subscribe and the exchange of data begin.

Comment: Good additional information. A few things and it's kind of bad news all the way around; Firebase is not really a desktop level database. While it can be done via a web, anything else is not supported - it's really designed for mobile devices. Second. Firebase is NOT a multi-tenant database (been there, done that) so if you are trying to use one Firebase for several independent customers it's not going to happen. Lastly, you can't really create a discreet Firebase per customer as the project you created in code points at an established Firebase which was initiated through the Firebase console.

Comment: However, maybe there are options so getting some input from one of the Firebaser's @FrankvanPuffelen may shed more light on it